# Toggle visiblity didn't work for some row?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use simple toggle function to show/hide detail of every element. Somehow it didn't work for some row. I've been looking to my code for hours and i can't see any error.

Code to display:

```
    <tbody>                                                
    <?php 
        $parent='';
             if( substr($row['element'],0,4) != 'ZONE') {
                 $parent_p = ( !empty($parent) ) ? $parent : '';
                 $parent = $row['element'];

                 if( !empty($parent_p) && $parent != $parent_p ) echo '</tbody>';
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$('#<?php echo $parent; ?>').toggle(500);"><img src="button_plus.png" width="10px"></a></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['element']; ?>></td>
                </tr>                                  
                <?php } else { // if ?>
                <?php if( $parent != $parent_p ) { ?>   
                <tbody style="display:none" id="<?php echo $parent; ?>">
                <?php $parent_p = $parent; ?>
                <?php } ?>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>- <?php echo $row['element']; ?></div></td>
                </tr>  
                <?php } // elseif ?>
    <?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

Some of the row like KEDAH/PERLIS, KUALA LUMPUR and SABAH didn't work. It suppose to show the child list like MELAKA.

[image]

Comment: Provide the html, we're not gonna interact much with an image.

Comment: You really need to show a sample of the HTML as it is not obvious what the `$parent`'s relationship is to the item clicked. There are much easier ways to do this, but you need to show your layout HTML first :)

Comment: @Jonast92 i've put my html

Comment: Close enough (the output HTML from a browser Save-As is normally *more useful* than PHP source). Have added an example I was mocking up in the meantime. if you can post output HTML instead I will match the code to that :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie what do you mean by output HTML form browser?

Comment: `form`, not `form`... Load your page in a web browser and do "File-Save-As" of the raw HTML. Otherwise use Chrome's F12 DOM inspector and cut & paste it from there.

Comment: The basic rule to take away from all this situation is to try and generate *clean* HTML output and leave the client-side processing to separate jQuery/JS code :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie this is my output http://pastebin.com/1FHY4TJ2

Comment: Answer below updated with your actual HTML in the new example. Now it is obvious how it should work (see what a difference having raw HTML makes) :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie i've tried ur code and it did work. TQ for ur time. But i just found out that the there is a special character in those row. So i just use str_replace function to replace it. Thanks again! Your code so much better than mine but i gonna use current code in the time being.

Comment: That is a terrible solution, but you don't work for me so feel free :)

Comment: PS. If my solution did solve the problem (whether you used it or not), please do mark it as "answer". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use attribute-base/inline event handles with jQuery. That adds a large overhead to the page and it can be replaced with an event handler attached using a single line of jQuery.

**Update for your specific situation**

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/9kzdu8w4/3/

You have hidden `tbody` elements following `tbody` elements, so the pattern is to toggle the next `tbody` using `closest('tbody')` to find the current `tbody` you clicked in.

1. Get rid of all the `onclick=` handlers and change the `href=` to `href="#"`
2. Remove all the `ignoreme=""` attributes (I did not have time to remove all the onclick handlers by hand so I renamed them).
3. add the following code:

jQuery:

```
 $(function () {
    // Listen for click events on any anchor in any TD in a table with ID="Table"
    $('#table td a').click(function (e) {
        // prevent the page moving to top when a bookmark # anchor is clicked
        e.preventDefault();
        // Toggle all the TRs following the current one, so long as they have class="detail"
        $(this).closest('tbody').next('tbody').toggle(500);
    });
 });
```

---

**Previous mockup below:**

**Example JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/9kzdu8w4/2/

Assuming you have a table has an id of "table", and the details to show are in following rows the HTML of each item would just look like this:

```
<table id="table">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#"><img src="button.png"></a>
        </td>
    <tr>
    <tr class="detail"><td>Some detail line</td></div>
    <tr class="detail"><td>Some detail line</td></div>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#"><img src="button.png"></a>
        </td>
    <tr>
    <tr class="detail"><td>Some detail line</td></div>
    <tr class="detail"><td>Some detail line</td></div>
</table>
```

and the required code could look like this:

```
$(function(){
    // Listen for click events on any anchor in any TD in a table with ID="Table"
    $('#table td a').click(function(e){
        // prevent the page moving
        e.preventDefault();
        // Toggle all the TRs following the current one, so long as they have class="detail"
        $(this).closest('tr').nextUntil(':not(.detail)').toggle(500);
    });
});
```

**notes:**

- `$(function(){ YOUR CODE });` is just a shortcut for `$(document).ready(function(){ YOUR CODE });` which wait until the DOM is ready before executing the function.
- [nextUntil](http://api.jquery.com/nextuntil/) is a handy jQuery method to retrieve sibling elements after the current one, until a specific condition is met.
- I used a `display: none` CSS style on the `detail` rows so they are initially hidden.